# Preserving $? output using multiple pipe statements using file-descriptors

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, pipe

On cli

I run

**no error**

```
cmd=$(uname -a) | awk '{print $1}'
echo $?
```

`0`

**with error**

```
   cmd=$(uname + -a) | awk '{print $1}'
    echo $?
```

`0`

Due to use of `|` i cannot preserve return error code from command 1,  I'm using `fd` as possible solution, but to no effect

**possible solution**

```
cmd=$(uname + -a) 3>&2| awk '{print $1}' 2>&3
```

`-bash: 3: Bad file descriptoruname: extra operand ‘+’`

**SOLVED**

```
cmd=$(uname -a | awk '{print $1}' 2>&1)

echo $?
```

value is non-zero.

Thanks everyone

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: with `error` ...`$?` should return non zero. The error is induced by putting `+` in uname command

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14270/187122. You can use the array `PIPESTATUS` to retrieve exit codes of commands from a pipeline.

Comment: I don't want to use `PIPE-STATUS` I want to solve it using `fd`

Comment: ``cmd=$(uname -a) | awk '{print $1}` `` seems broken to me. There is a single backtick at the end and the assignment is piped to `awk`.

Comment: @Socowi thanks its a typo

Comment: Ok, so you fixed the single backtick, but do you really want to pipe an assignment to `awk`? Assignments have no output, so I guess what you actually wanted to do was `cmd=$(uname -a | awk '{print $1}')`.

Comment: ...and if *that* were the goal, using the formulation above with either `set -o pipefail` or `PIPESTATUS` would be appropriate. File descriptor redirection, when not causing errors on its own, has *nothing at all to do* with `$?`, making the question nonsensical on its face; exit status isn't passed around via file descriptors in the first place.

Comment: @Socowi even with `cmd=$(uname + -a | awk '{print $1}')` i get `0` with `$?`. It should be non-zero!

Comment: @lazereyes, $? should be the same as the value returned by awk.  Which in this case is (almost certainly) 0.  One common technique for this is to do `cmd=$(uname ... | awk '{print $1}' | grep -q .` This is (IMO) the only place it is ever reasonable to pipe awk to grep, as you are using grep only for the purpose of producing an exit status.  Of course, you can do `awk '/./{ a = 1; print $1} END { exit !a }` to produce a similar result, but `... | grep -q .` if fairly idiomatic.

Comment: wrt your **SOLVED** code - that doesn't change a single thing about the exit status, you're still getting the exit status from awk, not uname. Do you REALLY need the specific exit status from uname or do you just need an exit status of 0 or 1 if the whole script produced output or not?

Comment: I want the complete command along with pipe to show   0 or 1, not just uname or awk, infact whatever is inside command substitution bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is all you really need:

```
cmd=$(uname -a | awk '{print $1; f=1} END{exit !f}')
echo "$?"
```

That will exit with status 0 if uname produces any output and awk succesfully reads/prints it, 1 otherwise.

Look:

```
$ cmd=$(uname -a | awk '{print $1; f=1} END{exit !f}')
$ echo "$?"
0

$ cmd=$(uname + -a | awk '{print $1; f=1} END{exit !f}')
uname: extra operand ‘+’
Try 'uname --help' for more information.
$ echo "$?"
1
```

Comment: it doesn't work, if uname syntax is wrong example `uname + -a`

Comment: Yes it does work. It can't NOT work or there's something very wrong with your shell. I updated my answer to show it working.

Comment: my bad i put `end` instead of `END`

Comment: `END` is a keyword that means you've come to the end of the input and so the associated action will be executed at that time. `end` is an unset variable with the value 0-or-null which is interpreted as a false condition when used in a conditional context and so the associated action will never be executed.

Comment: +1 so, in case of error in `uname` it should match `END` and exit with `!f` but value of `f` is kept inside the `{print $1; f=1}`. I'm bit confused of the flow.

Comment: If uname fails then nothing will be piped to awk so f will never be set to 1 so it'll be 0 in the END section so awk will exit !0 which is exit 1. The better way to think of it is in positive terms - if uname succeeds it will pipe output to awk which awk will print and set f to 1 and then in the END section awk will exit !1 (not one) which is exit 0 = success, if **anything** else happens (i.e. uname fails or awk fails) then awk will exit 1 or uname or awk will exit with 1 or some other non-zero value all of which = failure.